# What is the Dart code required to convert this JSON to a Dart class

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have a lot of json to parse in the form of Map<String, Map<String, List>> (I think?)

a small example is below to verify:

```
{"LEFT":{ "446927m": ["2020-02-21T03:01:04.023+00:00","2020-02-13T21:42:29.829+00:00"], "536278n": ["2019-10-04T07:06:09.878+00:00"]},

"MIDDLE":{ "938012c": ["2020-02-21T00:59:37.909+00:00","2020-01-23T22:39:46.789+00:00","2020-02-06T23:12:33.197+00:00"], "920283b": ["2020-02-07T04:16:39.994+00:00","2020-01-23T22:39:59.787+00:00"]},

"RIGHT":{ "192321k":["2020-02-20T21:31:32.437+00:00","2020-02-07T05:13:11.197+00:00"]}}
```

I am just having a hard time figuring out how to put this into a class so I can convert from JSON to Dart. LEFT, MIDDLE, and RIGHT are fixed, but there could be an unlimited number of strings, with 0 to 4 dates.

Comment: you can convert any json data for any language in this https://app.quicktype.io/ web please try :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can convert any json data for any language in this https://app.quicktype.io/ web please try :)

Comment: this site was able to generate the proper maps, and even recognised the dates as dates. Best JSON to class converter I have come across by a mile!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the converter function you can use to transform above JSON data into strictly typed object -

```
import 'dart:convert';

Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> convertData(String json) {
  //Our target type
  Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> convertedData = Map();

  //Convert JSON String to Dynamic Map
  Map<String, dynamic> jsonData = jsonDecode(json);

  //Converted Function
  jsonData.forEach((String key, dynamic value) {
    convertedData.putIfAbsent(key, () {
      Map<String, List<String>> data = Map();
      value.forEach((String dataKey, dynamic dataValue) {
        data.putIfAbsent(dataKey, () => List<String>.from(dataValue));
      });
      return data;
    });
  });

  //Return the result
  return convertedData;
}
```

Then you can use this function in the following way -

```
main() {

//Our Sample Data
  String sampleData = //JSON Data
      """{
   "LEFT":{
      "446927m":[
         "2020-02-21T03:01:04.023+00:00",
         "2020-02-13T21:42:29.829+00:00"
      ],
      "536278n":[
         "2019-10-04T07:06:09.878+00:00"
      ]
   },
   "MIDDLE":{
      "938012c":[
         "2020-02-21T00:59:37.909+00:00",
         "2020-01-23T22:39:46.789+00:00",
         "2020-02-06T23:12:33.197+00:00"
      ],
      "920283b":[
         "2020-02-07T04:16:39.994+00:00",
         "2020-01-23T22:39:59.787+00:00"
      ]
   },
   "RIGHT":{
      "192321k":[
         "2020-02-20T21:31:32.437+00:00",
         "2020-02-07T05:13:11.197+00:00"
      ]
   }
}""";

  print(convertData(sampleData));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `json.decode(jsonString)` to convert the json string to a  `Map<String, Map<String, List>>`

However, instead of parse the josn map keyword-by-keyword you should have a model class which allows to convert json maps into individual fields.

Check this site: [Json-to-Dart](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/)
Here if you copy/paste your json string. It will automatically generate the dart model class with teh toMap and from Map factory methods.

**NOTE:** To parse automatically, your key string should be same always. If they are not, then look for patterns e.g. string ending with `m` or `c` and then create your key out of it

Comment: I tried the json to dart, but it treats the Strings like it expects that String everytime, but it is almost always different:
eg:
class LEFT {
  List<String> l446927m;
  List<String> l536278n;

  LEFT({this.l446927m, this.l536278n});

  LEFT.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    l446927m = json['446927m'].cast<String>();
    l536278n = json['536278n'].cast<String>();
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['446927m'] = this.l446927m;
    data['536278n'] = this.l536278n;
    return data;
  }
}

Comment: Please check the NOTE section above

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy. Please use [Online JSON to Dart Convertor](https://www.dripcoding.com/json-to-dart/) to make dart object class from JSON response. Below is the Dart class for your json response generated using [JSON to Dart Convertor](https://www.dripcoding.com/json-to-dart/).

```
 class product_model {
  LEFT lEFT;
  MIDDLE mIDDLE;
  RIGHT rIGHT;

  product_model({this.lEFT, this.mIDDLE, this.rIGHT});

  product_model.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    lEFT = json['LEFT'] != null ? new LEFT.fromJson(json['LEFT']) : null;
    mIDDLE =
        json['MIDDLE'] != null ? new MIDDLE.fromJson(json['MIDDLE']) : null;
    rIGHT = json['RIGHT'] != null ? new RIGHT.fromJson(json['RIGHT']) : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.lEFT != null) {
      data['LEFT'] = this.lEFT.toJson();
    }
    if (this.mIDDLE != null) {
      data['MIDDLE'] = this.mIDDLE.toJson();
    }
    if (this.rIGHT != null) {
      data['RIGHT'] = this.rIGHT.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class LEFT {
  List<String> l446927m;
  List<String> l536278n;

  LEFT({this.l446927m, this.l536278n});

  LEFT.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    l446927m = json['446927m'].cast<String>();
    l536278n = json['536278n'].cast<String>();
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['446927m'] = this.l446927m;
    data['536278n'] = this.l536278n;
    return data;
  }
}

class MIDDLE {
  List<String> l938012c;
  List<String> l920283b;

  MIDDLE({this.l938012c, this.l920283b});

  MIDDLE.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    l938012c = json['938012c'].cast<String>();
    l920283b = json['920283b'].cast<String>();
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['938012c'] = this.l938012c;
    data['920283b'] = this.l920283b;
    return data;
  }
}

class RIGHT {
  List<String> l192321k;

  RIGHT({this.l192321k});

  RIGHT.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    l192321k = json['192321k'].cast<String>();
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['192321k'] = this.l192321k;
    return data;
  }
}
```