# How do I write a Dart model class which parses this JSON?

Tags: json, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on a dart / flutter app which I need to parse JSON from firebase database. I've done this successfully multiple times in my code except I can't get the following JSON to parse. Can someone help?

Here is the JSON response I'm working with:

```
{favorites: {-MH1vwWPqXHSXkTe_MxC: [Green Bay Packers, Washington Football Team]}, firstname: Mark, email: mbilner@gmail.com, lastname: bilner, username: mbil}
```

Here is my model class:

```
class userProf {
  String email;
  String firstname;
  String lastname;
  String username;
  List<String> favorites;

  userProf({this.email, this.firstname, this.lastname, this.username, this.favorites});

  factory userProf.fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic> parsedJson) {
    var favsFromJson = parsedJson['favorites'];
    List<String> favsList = new List<String>.from(favsFromJson);


    return userProf(
        email: parsedJson['email'],
        firstname: parsedJson['firstname'],
        lastname: parsedJson['lastname'],
        username: parsedJson['username'],
        favorites: favsList
    );
  }
}
```

The current code gives me the following error:
"Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable'"

This is how it is structured in the db:
[image]

Comment: That isn't even valid json, no?

Comment: @OldProgrammer The "JSON" output they show is likely after they decoded it and then printed the map that the decoder returned.

Comment: see my answer here :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/62888773/8388068

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can convert any json data for any language in this https://app.quicktype.io/ web please try :)

Comment: I made a small edit to the class but this works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think List 'from' method needs a Iterable value but 'favorites' value is 'Map'.

```
List<String> favsList = new List<String>.from(favsFromJson);
```

If you just use Map values only without key, you can like below.

```
List<String> favsList = [];
favsFromJson.values((value) => favList += value);
```